# Finding bounded lexicographically largest string of digits but not larger than other with counted substitutions

Tags: optimization, strings

The problem comes from the book текстовые и жадные алгоритмы (String and greedy algorithms) by a fairly unknown Russian computer scientist Николай Сухоруков.

We are given two numbers $A$ and $B$ of the same length but possibly with leading zeroes, which are bounded by $10^{(10^5)}$, but this is fine as this is a strings problem, and $k$ bounded by the number of digits of the larger.

When two numbers $p$, $q$ differ on exactly $l$ positions (including leading zeroes), we call them $l$-distant.

The objective of the problem is to find the largest $N$ which is $k$-distant of $A$ but less than $B$.

For example, given $A=0555, B=0551, k=3$ the solution is $N=0499$. Although there exist other, greater $N$s like $N'=0550$ or $N'=0549$, they cannot be reached by changing exactly three positions.

My first idea was to use a really trivial greedy algorithm, which fixed digits left-to-right. However, it did not pass a simple test of $$A=23, B = 12, k = 1$$
where the answer should be $N=03$, but the program yielded $N_{wrong}=13$.

My second thought was to use the parametric search algorithm, searching over $k$. However, I did not manage to come up with the sub-algorithm to be searched.

Binary search over $N$ also seems infeasible to me, due to sheer size of the number.

Do you have any ideas? I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Your greedy approach is already close to correct.  Your first task should be to check how many digits of $B$ you can replicate without using up your edit budget.  In the case that the resulting number is $< B$, you’re done.  But even if it goes over, you’ll only need to backtrack to the rightmost edit and decrement it by $1$, unless it is already $0$ in which case you can go back further left to decrement.  After that it’s just a matter of spending your remaining budget on $9$s immediately to the right.  Lexicographic order is very amenable to greedy approaches.

Comment: @ErickWong thanks for your help, if you move it into an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @ErickWong and how would I operate if $A=13131$ and $B=10101$? In this case, I would not be able to backtrack.

Comment: For $k=1$, for instance, after using up the budget to match $B$’s $10\ldots$, the resulting number is too large.  Since you can’t start with $10$, you have to go lower, so start with $0$, which consumes the budget and arrives at $03131$.  As long as you can solve the sub problem “does there exist a solution starting with prefix $P$?” then the lexicographic objective function tells you exactly where to look.